# no login credentials and can't get to grub

Tags: grub2, password-recovery

I have an old laptop on which I want to install ubuntu. I do not have the login credentials. I have found methods for accessing the /etc file, but I can not get it to boot into grub; neither f8, f12 nor shift works.

Comment: You have laptop. Any OS installed in it already? for which OS you don't have Credentials?

Comment: ubuntu; it's bypassing the grub screen, and I can't seem to get into grub; it starts  up ubuntu and neither the f8, f12 or shift key get me into grub. I can't get a boot menu and if I put in a live cd, nothing happens. I can't even connect to the internet because I don't have the privileges to do so.

Comment: after failing f8 and f12 is the system booting to default OS Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Boot into live usb or disk using your installer.
2. Select `Try Ubuntu` at the prompt.
3. Mount the `/` root partition and `chroot`:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
4. Change your password:

   ```
   sudo password root
   ```
5. Restart your computer, then alter the grub configuration:

   1. Change your grub configurations with `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` to get to grub menu:

      - Make this line: `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`, look like this `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=false`
      - Update the grub and make new configuration persist:

        ```
        sudo update-grub
        ```

Now after setting the `root` user password use that to find the other users on the system (if you don't know) and set their password accordingly.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery